# CakePHP Behaviors call to behavior method returns error

Tags: cakephp, behavior

I've been working with cakephp for personal use. Now I understood that I want to create some functions that will be repeated in many models of my project, so I found out by Cakephp docs that the best way to do it is using Behaviors.

**Objective:**
Each time a new entity of my project models are created, I want to notice some users(coworkers) by email. Like a new project added, new task added, etc...

**What achieved until now**
I created a behavior with an afeterSave event listener; I attached it in one of my models.
When I create I add a new task it runs the behaviors methods and send a simple email.

**Problem**
The problem is to find out witch model has called the event
I read the cake2.x docs and the afterSave event used to receive the event and the model in witch you could call alias to know the model name:

```
public function afterSave(Model $model,...){
     $model_name = $model->alias;
     if ($model_name == 'some_model'){
      //code for specific model
      } else (...)
 }
```

However in cakephp 3.9 we receive Event and EntityInterface:

```
public function afterSave(Event $event, EntityInterface $model)
   {
    
    # I tried $mail_HTMLmessage= $model->_registryAlias;
    # I tried $mail_HTMLmessage= $model->_className;
    # I tried $mail_HTMLmessage= $model->get('className');
    $this->sendMail($mail_HTMLmessage);// this is another method that i defined in my behavior that sends an email to me with the string mail_HTMLmessage as the mail message.

     return true;
   }
```

I've tested mail_HTMLmessage=$event->getName() and in my email I received event.afterSave as expected.
However everything I tried to get model/class name it returned an empty string.

Is it possible to get the model name? and what is the best way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is not in the event at all, but the entity. `getSource()`, to be specific.

Comment: Hi Greg, yes in fact that was my question how to get the model that in 3.9 its the entity. Sorry if I miss explained my self. I reviewd my post and in fact I have wrote wrong when I said that I obtained model.afterSave, I obtained event.afterSave and it was simply to show that the code was ok, just I could not obtain the model alias or name.
I will try getSource().
Thanks for your quick response

Comment: It worked prefecttly as expected;
public function afterSave(Event $event, EntityInterface $model)
   {
    $mail_HTMLmessage= $model->getSource(); 
    $this->sendMail($mail_HTMLmessage);// this is another method that i defined in my behavior that sends an email to me with the string mail_HTMLmessage as the mail message.
    
   }
In my email I recived de model name in plural like Tasks

Comment: **https://api.cakephp.org/3.9/class-Cake.ORM.Behavior.html#getTable()** @Osceptrus